# Javascript plug-in doesnt appear on drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

i want to put a soundcloud music player (http://stratus.sc/) on my drupalgardens page. i added an external source javascript library and uploaded a js file on the system as it says on the pluging website. all this tru the administration website of drupalgardens. When i check the sourcecode of my webpage it appears like the pluging is on the header. But it doesnt work, i cant see it. i activated all the jquery functions.

bit of sourcecode on header where the pluging seems there:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stratus.sc/stratus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://NAMEOFMYSITE/sites/NAMEOFMYSITE/files/js/js_PRNQJr2GPf-FrbaSuV5IDQ1l6Lfby6e79KpPOUTf5kI.js"></script>
```

link:

http://bit.ly/10nyAHV

Any suggestions?

Note : The player im talking about is NOT the one that can be seen under the rotating banner. the one im talking about its supposed to be globally on the webpage at its seem on the pluging oficcial webpage

Comment: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://juliocaroa.drupalgardens.com/ from frame with URL https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F87971730&color=5600ff&auto_play=false&show_artwork=true. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.

Comment: hey mate, its not that player, the one you can see its just on the mainpage, but this plugin acts on every page.

Comment: its a different pluging the one im talking about

Answer (score 1):

For one you're getting this console error: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "`
Not sure how that script is getting added but just removing the script tags may clear it up.

Even if the frame errors mentioned by KG are unrelated, you have to go clean that all up.

Your script should also be loaded after jquery. Since it looks like you have js aggregation turned on, I don't really know how to determine if drupal is loading things correctly. You can just tell your script to load in the footer instead of header if you're unsure. The links below explain how to do that.

Here are some javascript related resources for Drupal. They sometimes expect things to be handled differently.

The plugin is dependent on jQuery. By default, Drupal 7 loads jQuery 1.4. You may need to use the [jQuery Update plugin](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) to use 1.5, 1.7 or 1.8

Drupal Community docs about javascript:
http://drupal.org/node/756722

Drupal javascript API:
http://drupal.org/node/751744

Comment: hello kai, thanks for your reply, the problem i encounter here is that im using drupal gardens ( its part of an university assigment and i have to stick with it) it is supposed to work problerly with javascripts. I cant ipload or install stuff properly

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Some reasons for a not working player are:

- For some reason $ is not known (although jQuery is included). I replaced '$' by 'jQuery' and everything worked fine. That means use `jquery(document).ready(...` instead of `$(document).ready(...` and `jQuery.stratus({..` instead of `$.stratus({..`.
- There is a typo on the stratos.sc web site. It should read `$.stratus` not `$stratus` (or `jQuery.stratus`, see previous hint).
- Check that the source stratus.js and the initialisation code is included.

Mixture of https and http might be a good guess as reason for problems, but actually it works (I just tried it). If you can't find the problem, try to use a JavaScript debugger and check the error logs first!